# Drop down list not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

Why does the drop down list fades away when the mouse moves out of the very first element of the list.The list should fad out only when the mouse moves out of the entire list?Please help.

```
<html>
<head>

<style>
ul{
list-style-type:none;
}

li{
float:left;
}
#hidden2{
display:none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
    <li >
        <a href="#" onclick="return false;" onmousedown="hidden2.style.display='block'">Names</a> 
            <ul id="hidden2" onmouseout="style.display='none'"> 
                <li><a  href="#">Name1</a>
                    <a  href="#">Name2</a>
                    <a  href="#">Name3</a>
                    <a  href="#">Name4</a>
                </li>
            </ul>       
    </li>
</ul>
<body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please, post JS Code you have tried

Comment: Inline Js is used , check it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try onmouseleave instead of onmouseout

```
<ul>
    <li >
        <a href="#" onclick="return false;" onmousedown="hidden2.style.display='block'">Names</a> 
            <ul id="hidden2" onmouseleave="style.display='none'"> 
                <li><a  href="#">Name1</a>
                    <a  href="#">Name2</a>
                    <a  href="#">Name3</a>
                    <a  href="#">Name4</a>
                </li>
            </ul>       
    </li>
</ul>
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Qq5CZ/)

Comment: Thanks but it's not working in all browser as Torch .